# Таймаут в GetRequestStream() при получении потока из WebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, веб-программирование, timeout, httpwebrequest

Есть простой код отправляющий сообщения через Web API. В цикле формируется веб-запрос и отправляется. Проблема в том, что нормально выполняются только две итерации цикла. На третьей итерации зависает на строке получения стрима (var dataStream = request.GetRequestStream()) и отваливается по таймауту. В чем причина?

```
foreach (var channel in channels)
{
    var paramStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new TextMessage() { chat_id = channel.ToString(), text = txt });
    Byte[] postData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(paramStr);

    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(site);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.ContentLength = postData.Length;

    using (var dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        dataStream.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);

    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
}
```

Дополнения:
1. таймаут происходит ДО отправки запроса, на операции получения стрима запроса.
2. задержка на 3000 мс в итерации есть, она на результат не влияет.

Comment: Вероятнее всего хост, к которому вы подключаетесь защищается от флуда, т.е. просто не обрабатывает запросы, если они поступают слишком часто, возможно это даже оговорено в описании API ресурса. Попробуйте добавить временную задержку в 1-3 секунды между обращениями и посмотрите на результат. В приведенном коде на вид проблем не вижу.

Comment: Поинтересуйтесь у разработчиков сервиса, что не так с вашими запросами. Со стороны реализации отправки, проблем не видно.

Comment: А response закрывать уже не надо?

Comment: @VladD даже незакрытый ответ от сервера проблемой не считается? А ведь он занимает HTTP-соединение, которых всего два!

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Ну, я как-то думал, что response используется дальше и закрывается после этого. Потому что это не выглядит _полным_ кодом.

Comment: @VladD ну это же отправка данных на сервер. Вполне себе полный код...

Comment: Да, @VladD прав, дело было в не закрытом response. Теперь всё работает.